# Há um jeito de limpar a formatação do campo antes de passar pela validação?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou tentado procurar na net como resolvo isso e está tomando muito tempo, parece ser algo simples mas estou quebrando a cabeça, resolvi então criar um post aqui.

Estou usando Laravel 5.3 com MySQL em um ambiente provido pelo Laravel Homestead.

Em um form de cadastro de empresa tem o campo CNPJ que tem um mask que formata ele (ex.: 52.836.639/0001-05). Este campo está sendo guardado no banco sem a formatação, apenas com os números (ex.: 52836639000105). É um campo tipo CHAR(14).

A validação está sendo feita por um Request (EmpresaRequest) com as seguintes rules

```
public function rules()
   {
       return [
           'razao_social' => 'bail|required|max:128',
           'nome_fantasia' => 'required',
           'cnpj' => 'bail|required|unique:empresas|max:14'
       ];
   }
```

Mas o `unique` e o `max:14` não funciona, porque o dado está vindo formatado (com '.', '-' e '/') e no banco não está.

Eu já tentei usar um evento para testar uma possível correção, mas continua igual:

Coloquei isso no ***boot*** do ***AppServiceProvider***:

```
Empresa::saving(function ($empresa) {
    $empresa->cnpj = 12345678912345; // 14 characteres
});
```

A pergunta é:

**Neste modo de validação, há um jeito de limpar a formatação do CNPJ antes de passar pela validação?**

Comment: Como estás a fazer essa formatação? Antes de inserires na BD? para tranformar "52.836.639/0001-05" em "52836639000105" como fazes?

Comment: @Miguel, no método `store` estou fazendo um replace simples `$data['cnpj'] = str_replace(['-', '/', '.'], '', $data['cnpj']);` antes do `Empresa::create($data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
use Validator;
...


public function rules() {
    Validator::extend('cnpj_unique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $value = str_replace(['-', '/', '.'], '', $value); // tranformar input no mesmo formato que pode estar na BD
        return Empresa::where('cnpj', $value)->count() == 0; // verificar se já existe
    });

    return [
       'razao_social' => 'bail|required|max:128',
       'nome_fantasia' => 'required',
       'cnpj' => 'cnpj_unique|bail|required|max:14' // aqui colocas a tua nova rule costumizada
    ];
}
```

Para acresentar a tua mensagem de erro podes ir ao ficheiro da lang/validation.php:

```
...
"cnpj_unique" => "cnpj já existe",
...
```

[Mais sobre isto](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) (custom validation rules)

Ou um pouco mais simples, sem teres de extender:

Suponho que estejas a receber os dados a enviar como argumento os inputs vindos do form:

```
...
$inputs = $request->all();
$inputs['cnpj'] = str_replace(['.', ',', '/'], '', $inputs['cnpj']);

$validator = Validator::make($inputs, $this->rules());
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // falhou, redirect e enviar erros para o utilizador
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo! Só tive que modificar um pouco a query:

Comment: `\Validator::extend('cnpj_unique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $value = str_replace(['-', '/', '.'], '', $value); // tranformar input no mesmo formato que pode estar na BD
      return Farmacia::where('cnpj', $value)->get()->except($this->farmacia)->count() == 0; // verificar se já existe
     });`

Comment: Ha ok, percebi @LucasMartins, de qualquer maneira tens uma solução em baixo se te der mais jeito

Comment: é apenas na query `return Empresa::where('cnpj', $value)->get()->except($this->empresa)->count() == 0;` Para ele não comparar o CNPJ do mesmo registro quando estiver fazendo update, eu adicionei o `except($this->empresa)`

Comment: Ha ok, percebi sim @LucasMartins, desculpa não tinha essa informação. Mas agora está rersolvido (:

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a função `all()`.

```
public function rules(){
   return [
       'razao_social' => 'bail|required|max:128',
       'nome_fantasia' => 'required',
       'cnpj' => 'bail|required|unique:empresas|max:14'
   ];
}

public function all(){
   $input = parent::all();

   $cnpj = str_replace(['.', ',', '/'], '', $input['cnpj']);

   $input['cnpj'] = $cnpj;
   return $input;
}
```